# Finding the $n$-th derivative of $f(x) =e^x \sin x$, solving the recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, derivatives

I am trying to find a closed solution for the nth derivative of the function:

$f(x) = e^x \sin x$

So far I have been able to obtain the derivative as:

$f^{(n)}(x) = e^x S_n \sin x + e^x C_n \cos x$

The sequences S and C are defined as below:

$S_n = S_{n-1} - C_{n-1}$

$C_n = S_{n-1} + C_{n-1}$

$S_0 = 1$,
$C_0 = 0$

I have been able to further simplify this by combining the two equations and obtaining:

$C_n = 2S_{n-2}$

$S_n = S_{n-1} - 2 S_{n-3}$

However, I have no idea what to do now. Can anyone help me find the closed form solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recurrence $S_n=S_{n-1}-2S_{n-3}$ can be solved mechanically. Its auxiliary equation is $x^3-x^2+2=0$. By inspection $-1$ is a solution, so $x+1$ is a factor of the cubic: $$x^3-x^2+2=(x+1)(x^2-2x+2)\;.$$ The other roots are $$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-4}}2=1\pm i\;,$$ so the solution is of the form $S_n=A(-1)^n+B(1+i)^n+C(1-i)^n$. From the initial values $S_0=S_1=1$ and $S_2=0$ we get

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&A+B+C=1\\
&-A+B+C+Bi-Ci=1\\
&A+2Bi-2Ci=0
\end{align*}\right.$$

This system has the solution $A=0,B=C=\frac12$, so $$S_n=\frac12\left((1+i)^n+(1-i)^n\right)$$ and $$C_n=(1+i)^{n-2}+(1-i)^{n-2}\;.$$

Now $1+i=\sqrt2 e^{i\pi/4}$ and $1-i=\sqrt2 e^{-i\pi/4}$, so

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&S_n=2^{(n-2)/2}\left(e^{in\pi/4}+e^{-in\pi/4}\right)=2^{n/2}\cos\frac{n\pi}4\\
&C_n=2^{(n-2)/2}\left(e^{i(n-2)\pi/4}+e^{-i(n-2)\pi/4}\right)=2^{n/2}\cos\frac{(n-2)\pi}4=2^{n/2}\sin\frac{n\pi}4\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that $S_{n+4} = -4 S_n$ and $C_{n+4} =-4 C_n$.  So $S_{4k+j} = (-4)^k S_j$ and 
$C_{4k+j} = (-4)^k C_j$.  List the cases $j = 0$ to $3$ and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\left( \begin{array}{r} S_n\\C_n\\ \end{array} \right) &=
\left( \begin{array}{rr}
1 &-1\\
1 &1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} S_{n-1}\\C_{n-1}\\ \end{array} \right)\\
&=\left( \begin{array}{rr}
1 &-1\\
1 &1\\
\end{array}
\right)^n
\left(\begin{array}{c} S_{0}\\C_{0}\\ \end{array} \right)
\end{align}

Approach 1: Compute eigen-decomposition of the matrix and continue.

Approach 2: Eigenvalues are $(1+i)$ and $(1-i)$. Therefore, $S_n$ must be of the form $A(1+i)^n+B(1-i)^n$. Now, use values of $S_0$ and $S_1$ to compute $A$ and $B$. $A=B=1/2$.

After further simplification, we get
$$S_n = \sqrt{2^n} \cos \frac{n\pi}{4}, C_n = \sqrt{2^n} \sin \frac{n\pi}{4}$$

Comment: In fact, you can use euler's formula and definition of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in terms of $e^{ix}$ to simplify further.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

so $$f(x)=\frac{e^{(1+i)x}-e^{(1-i)x}}{2i}$$

Thus $$f'(x)=\frac{(1+i)e^{(1+i)x}-(1-i)e^{(1-i)x}}{2i}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{(1+i)^2e^{(1+i)x}-(1-i)^ne^{(1-i)x}}{2i}$$
Following in similar manner gives, $$f^n(x)=\frac{(1+i)^ne^{(1+i)x}-(1-i)^ne^{(1-i)x}}{2i}$$

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting method. I am sure this technique will be useful for future problems.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice way that makes use of complex exponentials and involves no nasty recurrence relations.

Start by noticing that $\sin x$ is the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$.

Define a function $F$ as follows:

$F(x)=e^xe^{ix}=e^x\cos x+i e^x \sin x$

The function $f(x)=e^x\sin x$ can now be expressed as the imaginary part of $F$:

$f(x)=Im(F(x))$

If you write $F$ as $F(x)=e^{(1+i)x}$ you can easily find its $nth$ derivative:

$F^{(n)}(x)=(1+i)^ne^{(1+i)x}=e^x \cdot(1+i)^ne^{ix}$

To make the extraction of the imaginary part of the above expression easier we can rewrite $1+i$ in polar form:

$1+i=\sqrt2 e^{i\pi /4}$

With this we  finally write $F^{(n)}(x)$ as:

$F^{(n)}(x)=e^x\cdot 2^{n/2}e^{in\pi /4}e^{ix}=2^{n/2}e^x e^{i(x+n\pi /4)}$

If you now take the imaginary part you find:

$f^{(n)}(x)=Im(F^{(n)}(x))=2^{n/2}e^x \sin (x+n\pi /4)$

Answer (score 1):

I introduced a complete solution to the problem of finding the $n$th derivative and the $n$th anti derivative of many classes of elementary and special functions. The problem you are trying to solve is covered under the power exponential class. See this [reference](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KZWIzZjIxZGQtN2M4NC00N2MzLTk1YmQtM2M2NmVhYmE4NzA5/edit?hl=en_US) (section 6) or [Ph.D. thesis, 2004](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB)  (page 85), where you find the general method.

Here is a formula found based on the general method

$$ f^{(n)}(x)={{\rm e}^{x}}{2}^{\frac{n}{2}}\sin \left( x+\frac{n\pi}{4}  \right)\,. $$