# what is the n times differentiation of $e^{3x}\cdot \sin^2x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have an equation **y = $e^{3x}\cdot \sin^2x$** and I want to **calculate n times differentiation** of it. As it is in the **form of uv** so I am lost here because at every iteration more term will generate and I don't know how to handle these kind of differentiation. My questions are -

> - What is the solution of this problem?
> - Are there any general rules for solving this kind of $n$ times differentiation?

*Please provide **step by step solution** and **proper references**.*

**Edited:**

If **Leibniz formula** can solve this problem then please suggest me some good book  where there will be some good examples so that I can understand it well.

Comment: I have voted to reopen, although this seems unlikely to succeed.  The phrases "step-by-step solution" and "proper references" are relative to a Reader's background, and the OP has not given much indication of his, other than by inference from his not easily digesting the given Answer.  I'll try to add some useful links as Comments on that answer.

Comment: Maybe trying a bit simpler problems first might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629155/finding-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex-sinx and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208002/finding-the-n-th-deriviative-of-fx-ex-sin-x-solving-the-recurrence-rel

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the leibniz formula $$D^n(fg) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} D^k(f) D^{n-k}(g).$$ You can easily compute $$D^{n-k}(e^{3x}) = 3^{n-k}e^{3x}$$ and $$D^{k}(\sin^2(x))=D^k\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right).$$ For this last derivative you have to discuss the parity of $k$, can you finish that ?

Comment: Actually i have no idea about this. Could you provide me with some examples or references where i can understand it.  @C. Dubussy

Comment: An (as yet) unanswered Question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145275/mixed-partial-derivative-product-rule) asks about extending products of two functions to more general products (of several functions), but provides a link to a paper that gives references and explores product rule generalizations in some depth.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) is intended to be accessible to general readers, but it is deficient in providing the sort of basic examples and references sought by the OP here.

Comment: I have tried Wikipedia but it wasn't help so much. Isn't there any book? As a novice, collecting information from different links without examples is quite hard :P @hardmath